# ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement onnxruntime==1.14.1 (from versions: none)

Tags: python, docker

I have read the onnxruntime [official document](https://onnxruntime.ai/docs/get-started/with-python.html) and found it support Python 3.6 - 3.9. then I changed the docker base image to `python:3.8.16-alpine3.17` , but still show error like this:

```
Collecting numba==0.56.4
  Downloading numba-0.56.4.tar.gz (2.4 MB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 2.4/2.4 MB 86.3 MB/s eta 0:00:00
  Preparing metadata (setup.py): started
  Preparing metadata (setup.py): still running...
  Preparing metadata (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ReadTimeoutError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=15)")': /simple/numpy/
Collecting numpy==1.24.2
  Downloading numpy-1.24.2.tar.gz (10.9 MB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 10.9/10.9 MB 87.2 MB/s eta 0:00:00
  Installing build dependencies: started
  Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'done'
  Getting requirements to build wheel: started
  Getting requirements to build wheel: finished with status 'done'
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): started
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): finished with status 'done'
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement onnxruntime==1.14.1 (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for onnxruntime==1.14.1
exit status 1
The command '/bin/sh -c pip3 install -r /root/chat-server/requirements.txt' returned a non-zero code: 1
Error: exit status 1
Usage:
  github-actions build-push [flags]

Flags:
  -h, --help   help for build-push
```

why still throw this error info? what should I do to avoid this issue? this is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.8.16-alpine3.17

LABEL jiangxiaoqiang (xxxx@gmail.com)

ENV LANG=en_US.UTF-8 \
    LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8 \
    TZ=Asia/Shanghai

RUN ln -snf /usr/share/zoneinfo/$TZ /etc/localtime \
    && echo $TZ > /etc/timezone \
    && mkdir -p /root/chat-server 

# upgrade pip
RUN pip install --upgrade pip && apk add --no-cache musl-dev gcc g++ libc-dev linux-headers curl

ADD . /root/chat-server/

EXPOSE 8001

RUN pip3 install -r /root/chat-server/requirements.txt
# RUN pip3 install -r /root/chat-server/requirements.txt -i https://mirrors.aliyun.com/pypi/simple/

WORKDIR /root/chat-server/
ENTRYPOINT exec python3 -m uvicorn main:app --port 8001 --host 0.0.0.0 --reload
```

and this is my dependencies:

```
fastapi==0.95.0
openai==0.27.0
sse-starlette==1.3.3
SQLAlchemy~=1.4.6
pydantic~=1.10.5
rembg==2.0.32
Pillow==9.5.0
aiohttp==3.8.4
aiosignal==1.3.1
anyio==3.6.2
async-timeout==4.0.2
asyncer==0.0.2
attrs==22.2.0
certifi==2022.12.7
charset-normalizer==3.1.0
click==8.1.3
coloredlogs==15.0.1
filetype==1.2.0
flatbuffers==23.3.3
frozenlist==1.3.3
h11==0.14.0
httptools==0.5.0
humanfriendly==10.0
idna==3.4
ImageHash==4.3.1
imageio==2.27.0
lazy_loader==0.2
llvmlite==0.39.1
mpmath==1.3.0
multidict==6.0.4
networkx==3.1
numba==0.56.4
numpy==1.24.2
onnxruntime==1.14.1
opencv-python-headless==4.7.0.72
packaging==23.0
Pillow==9.5.0
platformdirs==3.2.0
pooch==1.7.0
protobuf==4.22.1
pydantic==1.10.7
PyMatting==1.1.8
python-dotenv==1.0.0
python-multipart==0.0.6
PyWavelets==1.4.1
PyYAML==6.0
rembg==2.0.32
requests==2.28.2
scikit-image==0.20.0
scipy==1.10.1
sniffio==1.3.0
starlette==0.26.1
sympy==1.11.1
tifffile==2023.3.21
tqdm==4.65.0
typing_extensions==4.5.0
urllib3==1.26.15
uvicorn==0.21.1
uvloop==0.17.0
watchdog==3.0.0
watchfiles==0.19.0
websockets==11.0
yarl==1.8.2
psycopg2-binary==2.9.6
```

Comment: It seems that this package has problem with alpine. Does the dockerfile need to be based on alpine?

Comment: I want the finally image could be as small as possible, should I change to not  use alpine?

Comment: I've posted an answer with the changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To successfully build an image, change it from `-alpine` to standard Python. Then in the requirements file change `numpy==1.24.2` to `numpy`:

```py
FROM python:3.10

LABEL jiangxiaoqiang (xxxx@gmail.com)

ENV LANG=en_US.UTF-8 \
    LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8 \
    TZ=Asia/Shanghai

RUN ln -snf /usr/share/zoneinfo/$TZ /etc/localtime \
    && echo $TZ > /etc/timezone \
    && mkdir -p /root/chat-server 

# CHANGED: removed the dev packages:

# upgrade pip
RUN pip install --upgrade pip && apt install curl

ADD . /root/chat-server/

EXPOSE 8001

RUN pip3 install -r /root/chat-server/requirements.txt
# RUN pip3 install -r /root/chat-server/requirements.txt -i https://mirrors.aliyun.com/pypi/simple/

WORKDIR /root/chat-server/
ENTRYPOINT exec python3 -m uvicorn main:app --port 8001 --host 0.0.0.0 --reload
```

Comment: I follow your steps and problem solved but the image size up to 700MB+, it is too large for my server. I have to decrease the size of the image. but thank you for your patient.

Comment: @spark You can try the `-slim` tags ( https://hub.docker.com/_/python/tags?page=1&name=slim ). The generated images should have less size.